# How can i fix my problem with pyautogui.click?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Need to mention that im new with Python and i decided to create a bot for multiplayer game, to autobuy items on auctionhouse, using opencv and pyautogui, so far everything was going pretty well, the cursor was heading to the right point on the screen (reload auction), but

pyautogui.click(clicks=1) isnt working in game window.

IDE (PyCharm) is running with admin rights, googled alot about the topic, but nothing works so far. Will be pleased if anyone could help me, this is my first big project i really want to work with, so hopefully you guys can help me :D

additional info: game uses Battle Eye anticheat, engine Java (probably... Game is called Stalcraft, you can find it on steam, looks like its something Minecraft-based, but im not sure about it)
OS: Win 10 x64
Python:3.11

What i tried:

- pyautogui library (tried pyautogui.MoveTo(x,y) and the method with  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("whatever.png",confidence=0.85 Need to mention that first method works only in IDE, the second one based on img recognition also works with browser. Tried this in other apps, but no results. It's just hovering cursor on the right place, but no clicks at all)
- pydirectinput library

Here's what i got so far

````
import cv2
import random
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import imutils
import numpy as np
import pydirectinput

pyautogui.FAILSAFE=True

rng=random.uniform(0.87, 1.3)
sleep(5)
pyautogui.size()
print(pyautogui.size())
pyautogui.position()
print(pyautogui.position())

pyautogui.moveTo(x=1344, y=342, duration=rng)
pyautogui.click(1344, 342, clicks=5)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This might be very silly. But I had no luck with `.click`. In [my sample](https://github.com/mckornfield/wordscapes-cheat/blob/master/wordscape_player/highlighter.py#L33) I used `.moveTo` as you did, but then `.mouseDown()` and `.mouseUp()` to simulate a click. Also sometimes it required a delay between the two. I wonder if that combo would help instead?

```
pyautogui.mouseDown()
sleep(1)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

Comment: Same result as before, unfortunately.

Comment: Darn.. wonder if it's worth trying an alternative https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#some-similar-tools-for-comparison if things like the browser work fine...